# my website automatically resizes to fit my iphone screen but the images are out of place, how do i fix this?

Tags: css, iphone, responsive-design

The images/text/background stay together in every screen size available on my desktop, but on my iphone, the text, background, and images resize out of order.  All the @media changes, I make in my CSS, aren't affecting my iphone.  1.) How do I make changes to my css so that they appear on my iphone, and 2.) How do I resize my website so that everything stays together on my iphone.  More specifically, how do I resize the images so that they are relative to the text on my iphone sized screen?

Below is an example of the css I'm using for each image on my website.

```
#dragon-image{
position:absolute;
z-index:2;
padding-top:100px;
padding-left:440px;
```

}

```
#dragon-image img{
width:340px;
```

}

I don't even know where to begin.  The website is [How to Make Kombucha Tea](http://howtomakekombuchatea.com/)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

[image]

it looks like the original on the phone no???

put this in your html head

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: @ittles if you work with media use the inspector and you can try how it look on the mobile time you build your code

Comment: I did try but your CSS @media is not done for "media" you do not for exemple: line 4283 in your CSS #info-body --> width 780px and height: 1298px w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: The code made my navigation bar really weird and it didn't fix the image problem.  Is there a way to just make my mobile version exactly like my desktop version?  That's all I'm trying to do.  The mobile version is almost exactly like my desktop version except all the images are out of place on the mobile version.